# Performance when reading and updating xml file in application

Tags: c#, xml, performance

My application is dealing with several xml files (CRUD). The maximum size of the file is about 150kb.

I have a question : should I create a "handle" of the file at the beginning of the application and use it globally, right now I'm using a static member :

```
Public static class XmlFile1
{
    static XElement XmlTree = XElement.Load(pPath);

    public static string Read()
    {
        // read something from XmTree
    }

    public static string Update()
    {
        // update something in XmTree and save the file rightaway 
        XmlTree.Save(pPath);
    }

    // insert , delete method ... (same as Update() )
}
```

I'm using it like this :

```
Public class Test
{
    public dosomething()
    {
        XmlFile1.Read();
        XmlFile1.Update(); 
        // .... 
    }
}
```

Is this a good approach? Or should I load the file to XElement every time the application performs a CRUD operation?

P/s : even if I have to re-load the file to XElement every time calling the CRUD functions, I still have to save the file immediately after very changes the application has made to the file (now is a XElement object), because I don't want to lost any data lost due to power failure or unhandled exception ...

Comment: There is no need to reload what you have just saved. If you want to save to persistent storage periodically to avoid data loss, then go right ahead. I'm assuming that each operation is conceptually atomic.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I meant should I keep the xElement object of the file throughout the application life-time? Will it affect the overall performance? Btw If I don't keep the xElement object alive (by using a static member like above), every time I read or update from the file I will have to load it again? This will affect performance too I think!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what your specific concerns were. Honestly, whether or not it is a good idea to use a static variable really depends on the kind of application you are writing. Is this a web app? Will multiple users be able to edit the same record? How long does you app run on average?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry for the lack of information. My app is a desktop app and won't have multiple users and instances running at the same time. And my app will run on an average of 1-2 hours maximum each time it's activated.

Comment: I would say a static is fine. On the other hand, if there are multiple screens/tabs that are unrelated to that specific XML document, you may want to tie the lifetime to the view associated with the document, reloading it when the user enters or re-enters it. What you do not want to do is keep the file itself open.